# Copy site collection without duplicating guids

Tags: 2010, powershell

On our DEV farm I've got a site collection containing a variety of sites and subsites within. Many of them came from our PROD farm. Now, I'd like to copy this site collection on our DEV farm back to the PROD farm. Problem is, if I use the typical powershell "backup site collection" method, the GUIDs end up getting duplicated. This was no problem going from PROD > DEV, but now that I want to go from DEV > PROD as additional content (not replacing the original on PROD). I hit that GUID problem.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Export-SPWeb will not duplicate GUIDs and may be an option depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Try using import/export. The main difference between import/export and backup/restore is that import/export generates new Guids.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428301.aspx